# Replace keys from the hash by values from the hash

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a hash (with hundreds of pairs) and I have a string.

I want to replace in this string all occurrences of keys from the hash to according values from the hash.

I understand that I can do something like this

```
some_hash.each { |key, value| str = str.gsub(key, value) }
```

However, I am wondering whether there is some better (performance wise) method to do this.

Comment: Don't wonder, run some benchmarks and see for yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to run `gsub` once. Since regex (oniguruma) is implemented in C, it should be faster than looping within Ruby.

```
some_hash = {
  "a" => "A",
  "b" => "B",
  "c" => "C",
}

"abcdefgabcdefg".gsub(Regexp.union(some_hash.keys), some_hash)
# => "ABCdefgABCdefg"
```

Comment: This is one of my favorite things about Ruby. `gsub` with regexp and a hash.

Comment: Wait, It may be actually slower than your iterating way. Please test with your data and unaccept this answer it if you are not satisfied with the performance. Sorry.

Comment: Don't doubt the `gsub`. It's extremely fast.

Comment: Good to know that. I am relieved. Thanks.

Comment: @akuhn I feel that there is nothing used here that is specific to Ruby 1.9. Which part did not work?

Comment: @sawa passing in a hash as the second argument did not work. I get `TypeError: can't convert Hash into String`

Answer (score 2):

Some benchmarks:

```
require 'benchmark'

SOME_HASH = Hash[('a'..'z').zip('A'..'Z')]
SOME_REGEX = Regexp.union(SOME_HASH.keys)

SHORT_STRING = ('a'..'z').to_a.join
LONG_STRING = SHORT_STRING * 100

N = 10_000

def sub1(str)
  SOME_HASH.each { |key, value|
    str = str.gsub(key, value) 
  } 
  str
end

def sub2(str)
  SOME_HASH.each { |key, value|
    str.gsub!(key, value) 
  } 
  str
end

def sub_regex(str)
  str.gsub(SOME_REGEX, SOME_HASH)
end

puts RUBY_VERSION
puts "#{ N } loops"
puts
puts "sub1: #{ sub1(SHORT_STRING) }"
puts "sub2: #{ sub2(SHORT_STRING) }"
puts "sub_regex: #{ sub_regex(SHORT_STRING) }"
puts

Benchmark.bm(10) do |b|

  b.report('gsub')  { N.times { sub1(LONG_STRING)      } }
  b.report('gsub!') { N.times { sub2(LONG_STRING)      } }
  b.report('regex') { N.times { sub_regex(LONG_STRING) } }

end
```

Which outputs:

```
1.9.3
10000 loops

sub1: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
sub2: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
sub_regex: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

                user     system      total        real
gsub        14.360000   0.030000  14.390000 ( 14.412178)
gsub!        1.940000   0.010000   1.950000 (  1.957591)
regex        0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.075038)
```